# Problem with all day events on iPad calendar spanning multiple days instead of one

Tags: ipad, ical

I'm having an issue editing all day events on my iPad calendar. If I reschedule an event to the following day, it now spans the two days instead of just one.

The issue only happens on my iPad. I can reschedule appointments on my iPhone without any problems. Date and time zone are set correctly.

Comment: Is the start of the all-day event at midnight? I found when changing timezones (in real life, not as a setting), the day-long events automatically reset themselves to straddle two days, but still 24 hours in length - just a different start time. There's a setting in `Mail, Contacts, Calendars` right at the bottom, under `Calendar`, where you set Time Zone Support. Does it match the iPad's timezone?

Comment: Yes, both time zones on the iPhone and iPad are correct, and in sync.